# Can an uncountable group $G$ have countably many distinct non isomorphic subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can an uncountable group $G$ have **only** countably many distinct non isomorphic subgroups?I'm unable to produce a example.Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Nielsen-Schreier theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem), every subgroup of a free group is free. It follows that a free group on $\aleph_\alpha$ generators, where $1\le\alpha\lt\omega_1,$ is an uncountable group with only countably many nonisomorphic subgroups.

Comment: Why is it uncountable?

Comment: Soz, I had read $\alpha$ generators.

Comment: @bof Thank you for Beautiful answer.Regards,

Answer (score 6):

Given any set $X$, the free Abelian group $\Bbb Z[X]$ is of size $|X|+\aleph_0$, and it has exactly $|X|$ generators. Moreover, if $G$ is a free Abelian group with $|X|$ generators, then they are isomorphic.

So if $X$ is any set such that $\{|Y|\mid Y\subseteq X\}$ is a countable set, $\Bbb Z[X]$ will have exactly that many non-isomorphic subgroups. As bof notes in his answer, taking any $|X|<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ will do, and if $\aleph_1\leq|X|$ then the resulting group is indeed uncountable.